# Solr exclusions by query and many values

Tags: solr

we have Solr docs for manufacturer parts, where each part is available from
100's of suppliers. those suppliers are stored within each Mfg part document
in a multi-field.

customers search our parts by keyword against part titles and
descriptions, where each customer has a unique list of what suppliers they are not allowed
to view. For example:

```
solr docs:
doc_id = 1, mfg_part = abc, suppliers = s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7
doc_id = 2, mfg_part = def, suppliers = s4, s5, s6, s7
doc_id = 3, mfg_part = ghi, suppliers = s4
doc_id = 4, mfg_part = jkl, suppliers = s1, s2, s3, s4
doc_id = 5, mfg_part = mno, suppliers = s1, s2, s3, s5

customer A: exclude suppliers: s4, s5, s6, s7
customer B: exclude suppliers: s1, s2, s3, s4

when customer A searches, documents 2 & 3 should not be returned in any
result set
when customer B searches, documents 3 & 4 should not be returned in any
result set
```

one thought we have is to restructure our docs so that there is one doc per
supplier mfg part, instead of per mfg part, but the result would be an index
of 3000 times the size!!! Many of our mfg parts have 1000 or more suppliers.
Currently we shove exclude lists into the filter query, but its getting to
be quite

we have looked at Solr "join" in Solr 4, but being this is a production
site generating millions of dollars per week, we cannot afford to use alpha
or beta versions of software.

finally, we currently use a INclusion list of suppliers in a filter query, which works, but its awfully slow since the inclusion list is in the 1000's. We would rather use an EXclusion list, but cannot figure out the query or schema to use.

Any ideas, anyone?

thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

For Solr authorization people usually use [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html).

Take a look [here](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/wright-nokia-manifoldcfeurocon-2011).